# Disable radio buttons contained in Box

Tags: swift, macos, cocoa

I have a set of radio buttons that are placed within a box.

[image]

When the user selects an option, these buttons needs to be disabled. I cannot find a relevant property to disable all items within the box.Only option I can find is to set the hidden property.

```
    box.isHidden=true
```

Comment: You can't disable a box, disable the buttons instead.

Answer (score 0):

`NSButton` inherts from `NSControl`, which has an `isEnabled` property. If you want your radio buttons to still be visible but not clickable, use that.

Comment: So I have to set the isEnabled property for every radio button separately.

Comment: Yes, that's correct.